# How to skip the functions while error occurs in node js step library?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using step library for synchronous behavior for validating and saving contacts,

Following are the code which i am using right now

```
exports.actions = function(req, res, ss) {

var Step= require('step');
req.use('session');

return {

        addCon:function(contactObject){

        Step(
        function validation(){
            var accounts =contactObject.contacts.accounts;
            accounts.forEach(function(){
                //database call
                services.user.get(updateObj,function(err,rec){

                    if(err || rec == null)
                     {
                        res("Saving Contact Failed,user Does Not Exist");
                        //here responding to client for showing alert message
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(userId === rec.friendId){
                        res("Error");
                        //here responding to client for showing alert message
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
        },
        function saving(){
            //saving 
        }
        ,
        function pusblishing tofriend(){
            //stuff
        }
        )

        }
 }

  }
```

Actually i want to skip the saving function if any error occurs in the validation function.
and any idea tobreak the loop, return false is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on step but it appears you can pass it `this` as a callback function which will give you the ability to pass on errors and then to throw errors (as in the [documentation](https://github.com/creationix/step)).

The problem you have is you're returning in the functions of the loop so it will end that function and not the bigger `Step` function. You're better off passing a `this` function in the end of one of the functions like this, and doing the error checking later:

```
Step(
    function hello() {
        console.log('Hello');
        this(err, 'Hello');
    },
    function howareyou (err, greeting) {
        if (err) return something ...
```

Step will stop when you return in on one of the main functions it is trying to step through.

However, it looks for your use case, it would be better to use the async library's [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) which has something similar to what you're describing built in AND you can handle errors in a single error function in the end.